# Using realloc in c++

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, realloc

`std::realloc` is dangerous in c++ if the malloc'd memory contains non-pod types.  It seems the *only* problem is that `std::realloc` wont call the type destructors if it cannot grow the memory in situ.

A trivial work around would be a `try_realloc` function.  Instead of malloc'ing new memory if it cannot be grown in situ, it would simply return false.  In which case new memory could be allocated, the objects copied (or moved) to the new memory, and finally the old memory freed.

This seems supremely useful.  `std::vector` could make great use of this, possibly avoiding all copies/reallocations.
*preemptive flame retardant:* Technically, that is same Big-O performance, but if vector growth is a bottle neck in your application a x2 speed up is nice even if the Big-O remains unchanged.

BUT, I cannot find any c api that works like a `try_realloc`.

Am I missing something?  Is `try_realloc` not as useful as I imagine?  Is there some hidden bug that makes `try_realloc` unusable?

Better yet, Is there some less documented API that performs like `try_realloc`?

*NOTE:* I'm obviously, in library/platform specific code here.  I'm not worried as `try_realloc` is inherently an optimization.

---

*Update:*
Following Steve Jessops comment's on whether `vector` would be more efficient using realloc I wrote up a proof of concept to test.  The `realloc-vector` simulates a vector's growth pattern but has the option to realloc instead.  I ran the program up to a million elements in the vector.

For comparison a `vector` must allocate 19 times while growing to a million elements.

The results, if the `realloc-vector` is the only thing using the heap the results are awesome, 3-4 allocation while growing to the size of million bytes.

If the `realloc-vector` is used alongside a `vector` that grows at 66% the speed of the `realloc-vector`  The results are less promising, allocating 8-10 times during growth.

Finally, if the `realloc-vector` is used alongside a `vector` that grows at the same rate, the `realloc-vector` allocates 17-18 times.  Barely saving one allocation over the standard vector behavior.

I don't doubt that a hacker could game allocation sizes to improve the savings, but I agree with Steve that the tremendous effort to write and maintain such an allocator isn't work the gain.

Comment: It's hard to provide platform specific suggestions with no idea of the platform you want to target.

Comment: My target is gcc + Linux.  However, I'm generally curious so a solution on any platform will be considered.

Comment: I can't help to think: If you want the best performance, use vector.reserve() so you don't have to grow the vector at all.

Comment: @kotlinski: but you cannot always do that. Otherwise the dynamic growth property of the vector class would be redundant anyway.

Comment: If the copy performance of the objects your `vector` is holding is terrible, and you cannot use a `deque` for whatever reason, then maybe you should change your `vector` over to hold `shared_ptr` instances that point to the objects. That way the copy operations will become a lot cheaper. I'm not sure if `unique_ptr` objects can be used in standard containers but that would reduce copying overhead even further.

Comment: To be able to use realloc (or similar) with non-POD (plain old data) in C++ you would not only need to be able to call destructors in case of failure, but also in the case of shrinking an array. It would also have to call the default constructor on new members of the array in the case that the array was being grown. Another thing that might need to be considered would be if moving an object might cause some problem; classes might then need to implement a move method that was sort of a destructor-reconstructor that had references to both the old and the new data but order of move might matter.

Comment: +1 for update with concrete results!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`vector` generally grows in large increments. You can't do that repeatedly without relocating, unless you carefully arrange things so that there's a large extent of free addresses just above the internal buffer of the vector (which in effect requires assigning whole pages, because obviously you can't have other allocations later on the same page).

So I think that in order to get a really good optimization here, you need more than a "trivial workaround" that does a cheap reallocation if possible - you have to somehow do some preparation to *make* it possible, and that preparation costs you address space. If you only do it for certain vectors, ones that indicate they're going to become big, then it's fairly pointless, because they can indicate with `reserve()` that they're going to become big. You can only do it automatically for all vectors if you have a vast address space, so that you can "waste" a big chunk of it on every vector.

As I understand it, the reason that the `Allocator` concept has no reallocation function is to keep it simple. If `std::allocator` had a `try_realloc` function, then either every Allocator would have to have one (which in most cases couldn't be implemented, and would just have to return false always), or else every standard container would have to be specialized for `std::allocator` to take advantage of it. Neither option is a great Allocator interface, although I suppose it wouldn't be a huge effort for implementers of almost all Allocator classes just to add a do-nothing `try_realloc` function.

If `vector` is slow due to re-allocation, `deque` might be a good replacement.

Comment: I'm working under the assumption that `try_realloc` is trivially cheap.  When a `vector`'s capacity is exceeded instead of the default exponential growth it would use `try_realloc` to increase the capacity by one.  When `try_realloc` can no longer grow without reallocation, then allocate twice the memory needed, do the standard copy/move stuff, doubling the capacity.

Comment: Generally I don't see why a try_realloc should be much faster than a malloc.

Comment: @caspin: How is that any more efficient than what `vector` actually does, though, which is (for the sake of argument) still to double its capacity each time it relocates? All you gain, I think, is that in your version the extra memory isn't "really allocated" yet, so it's available to be allocated for some other use. If it isn't so used, then there's no difference, and if it is so used then you've actually *slowed down* the vector, since your `try_realloc` will fail earlier than my extra capacity is used up. Even in my version, with overcommit you can avoid "really using" physical memory.

Comment: @caspin: I think your way gains in the case where, purely by luck, there's a large extent of free memory just above the buffer, at the time the vector wants to extend into it. Which is fine, but as I say I think it's too rare to be worth building into the interface, given that `deque` exists to support situations where the growth is unpredictable and copy performance is awful. Maybe the authors of the standard think likewise, or maybe they have some other reason - I don't know.

Comment: @caspin: Fair point. If `vector` is willing to make platform-specific assumptions/guesses, then it could in theory ensure that its sequence of increased capacities fits neatly into the block sizes actually provided by the memory allocator, so that this bad case of vector performance never happens. That sequence might be 32, 64, 128, or might perhaps be 24, 56, 120. If you want to make this part of the portable Allocator interface, I think you're going to a lot of effort just to avoid using `deque` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You could implement something like the `try_realloc` you proposed, using `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `MAP_FIXED` and `mremap` with `MREMAP_FIXED`.

**Edit**: just noticed that the man page for mremap even says:

> mremap() uses the Linux page table
>   scheme.  mremap() changes  the 
>   mapping  between
>          virtual addresses and memory pages.  This can be used to implement
>   a very efficient
>          realloc(3).

Comment: Problem with that is that the minimum allocation with `mmap` is a page, and that's massive overkill for most vectors.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't think there are any sub-page sized allocators that can offer this and if it's significantly smaller than the size of a page or so the performance benefits would probably be negligible anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`realloc` in C is hardly more than a convenience function; it has very little benefit for performance/reducing copies. The main exception I can think of is code that allocates a big array then reduces the size once the size needed is known - but even this might require moving data on some `malloc` implementations (ones which segregate blocks strictly by size) so I consider this usage of `realloc` really bad practice.

As long as you don't constantly reallocate your array every time you add an element, but instead grow the array exponentially (e.g. by 25%, 50%, or 100%) whenever you run out of space, just manually allocating new memory, copying, and freeing the old will yield roughly the same (and identical, in case of memory fragmentation) performance to using `realloc`. This is surely the approach that C++ STL implementations use, so I think your whole concern is unfounded.

**Edit**: The one (rare but not unheard-of) case where `realloc` is actually useful is for giant blocks on systems with virtual memory, where the C library interacts with the kernel to relocate whole pages to new addresses. The reason I say this is rare is because you need to be dealing with very big blocks (at least several hundred kB) before most implementations will even enter the realm of dealing with page-granularity allocation, and probably much larger (several MB maybe) before entering and exiting kernelspace to rearrange virtual memory is cheaper than simply doing the copy. Of course `try_realloc` would not be useful here, since the whole benefit comes from actually *doing the move* inexpensively.

Comment: I'd think that once allocation grows to megabytes, the absolute overhead of exponential allocation strategy may start becoming an issue, so having optimization only in that size range would still be good. Another case where realloc is good is, when there's a loop which reallocates just one memory block, which should eventually end up in heap location where it can be grown without copying. And also absolute cost of copy increases with block size, so again optimization only applying to big blocks is still good.